# Value Change with serialization

Tags: java, serialization

Let the value of an java object initially be x. Does the value of this object changes to some other value if the object has been serialized first followed by deserialization ?

```
public void serDesSaveTenantConfigWithoutActivation() {
    JaxbSerializer serializer = new JaxbSerializer();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(TMN_VMSIZE, "LITE");
    props.setProperty(TMN_VMCOUNT, "1");
    props.setProperty(WN_IFL_VMCOUNT, "1");
    props.setProperty(WN_IFL_VMSIZE, "LITE");
    props.setProperty(WN_IFL_VIRTUALSERVER, "sn");

    final SaveTenantConfigCommand cmd = new SaveTenantConfigCommand("bingo");
    cmd.setProperties(props);
    cmd.setAuditInformation(new AuditInformation("bingo", "isource"));
    serializer.serializeObject(cmd, sw, null);
    String serXml = sw.toString();
    log.debug(serXml);        assertNotNull(serXml);
    final StringReader reader = new StringReader(serXml);
    final SaveTenantConfigCommand deserCmd = serializer.deserializeObject(reader, SaveTenantConfigCommand.class);
    assertEquals(cmd.getTenantId(), deserCmd.getTenantId());
    assertEquals("LITE", deserCmd.getProperties().getProperty(TMN_VMSIZE));
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code? It is not really clear to me what you mean with 'x'

Comment: X is any random value . Lets take it as some integer may be say 10. Does this value change ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly since the whole idea of serialization is to represent the object as bytes and being able to restore that to an Object later. So in short the answer is 'no' :-)

Comment: So If I write assertEquals( a,b) where a is any value initally and b is the value after serialization first, followed by deserialization, then the above will always return true?

Comment: In theory of an Integer yes, but can you show your code so we can confirm this?

Comment: You could modify the serialized bytes and it would deserialize differently, but of course it doesn't change by itself.

Comment: I have uploaded the code . At the last you can see there are three assertEquals Statement. So If it always returns true so whats the use of these statements ?

Answer (score -1):

**No.** **Serialization** is a way of writing the **state of an object** into a byte stream.
Please refer a [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/serialization-in-java) to get idea of **Serialization** and **Deserialization**.